# Consume bad data in text file java

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DemoEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("BP.txt"));

        int badData = 0;
        int goodData = 0;

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            try {
                int value = in.nextInt();
                if (value < 0)
                    throw new BPIllegalValueException("value cannot be less than zero");
                else goodData++;
            } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                // Consume badData
                badData++;
            } catch (BPIllegalValueException ex) {
                badData++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("gooddata" + goodData);
        System.out.println("baddata" + badData);
    }
}

public class BPIllegalValueException extends Exception {
    BPIllegalValueException(String message){
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

I'm writing a program the reads a txt file and then outputs the number of pieces of "good" and "bad" data with good data being any non-negative integer number and bad data being anything else.
However, I'm not sure how to consume and move to the next piece of data if my program encounters a string.

Comment: Read it in as a `String`. If it matches a number `0-9+`, then it's good. Otherwise it's bad.

Comment: Please format your code, use indentions and less empty lines. The code right now is very hard to read.

Comment: Well you already seem to be consuming strings which cannot be successfully parsed into integers at that `catch` block?

Answer (score 0):

Loop with a check on encountering the int:

```
if (in.hasNextInt()) {
    ... all
} else {
    ++badData();
    in.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do You mean by "consume"? You propably want to advance to another token. Reading the documentation should give You the answer:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()

next() method will allow You to go to a next token...